# How to get a list of functions defined in a Haskell source file (for semantic analysis)?

Tags: haskell

I've found https://github.com/github/semantic however this does not yet seem to support Haskell source code.

I highly suspect such a library exists, however it's quite difficult to get **relevant** results from a web search.

What library supports this, ideally something fairly simple?

I suppose the defacto parser for Haskell in Haskell is GHC itself, but I'd assume interfacing with this would be difficult.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look how Haddock does this: https://github.com/haskell/haddock/tree/ghc-8.10/haddock-api/src

Comment: [`haskell-src-exts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) is the most widely used third-party Haskell parser, as far as I know

Comment: https://github.com/blitzcode/hackage-diff might be useful to look at for this (also uses the haskell-src-exts library)